# Keys getting shuffled when converting a list to dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf

I'm trying to extract keys from a dictionary. After extracting, I'm storing them in a list and converting them back to a dict. While doing so, I'm getting a shuffled output of the keys. The order is not conserved. Using Python 3.8. Please help. Thank you!

```
output = {'aimless': 6.922918004572872,
  'distressed': 7.922918004572872,
  'drifting': 64.922918004572872,
  'nearly': 16.922918004572872,
  'attempting':856.922918004572872,
  'artiness': 3.922918004572872,
  'existent': 2.922918004572872,
         }
sorted_freq = dict(sorted(output.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
nocab = list(sorted_freq.keys())
nocab = nocab[::-1]
brocab = {key for key in nocab}
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```
{'aimless',
 'artiness',
 'attempting',
 'distressed',
 'drifting',
 'existent',
 'nearly'}
```

**The output I want (sorted according to their values in output):**

```
{'attempting',
 'drifting',
 'nearly',
 'distressed',
 'aimless',
 'artiness',
 'existent'}
```

Comment: You should try to provide a [mre], most of the code here is irrelevant to your problem and only obfuscates it.

Comment: could you please check your python version? > As of Python version 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. In Python 3.6 and earlier, dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I'm sorry it seems that way.  Please check the latter bold part.  That is the output I want. What it means is already specified in the 'My output' part.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Please check the edited question. Hope it follows the guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Keys of Python `dict` is unordered until 3.7.

If you need the keys to be ordered, try `collections.OrderedDict`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

**Edit:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

output = {'aimless': 6.922918004572872,
  'distressed': 7.922918004572872,
  'drifting': 64.922918004572872,
  'nearly': 16.922918004572872,
  'attempting':856.922918004572872,
  'artiness': 3.922918004572872,
  'existent': 2.922918004572872,
         }
sorted_freq = OrderedDict(sorted(output.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

```
> sorted_freq 

OrderedDict([('attempting', 856.9229180045729),
             ('drifting', 64.92291800457288),
             ('nearly', 16.92291800457287),
             ('distressed', 7.922918004572872),
             ('aimless', 6.922918004572872),
             ('artiness', 3.922918004572872),
             ('existent', 2.922918004572872)])
```

If you need only the keys:

```
> list(sorted_freq.keys())

['attempting',
 'drifting',
 'nearly',
 'distressed',
 'aimless',
 'artiness',
 'existent']
```

Comment: Hi, I checked my version, it's 3.8.6. Using `OrderedDict` gives me a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Can you please pass us the code with `OrderedDict`?

Comment: I was getting the same output without `OrderedDict` as well. What I want is a dictionary of these values in the list

Comment: Wait a sec... do you want your output as a `dict` or a `set`? Because your example output is a set. If all you need is a sorted `dict`, then `sorted_freq` is already it.

Comment: I want a `dict` of only the keys in `sorted_freq`. Your last code snippet is what I want but in the form of a `dict`, not even `dict_keys()`

Comment: There is nothing in Python which contains only the keys - a dict is a key-value pair. What you are actually showing in expected output (`brocab`) is actually a `set`, which has no order. Try `type(brocab)` and see.

Comment: You have 2 options: either use a list, or an ordered dict with `None` as values.